# No group can have exactly 3 elements of order 3 (T/F)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

True of False? This is a question from a past exam that I'm practicing on. Thanks.

Comment: One can use a theorem of Frobenius to see that the number of solutions to $x^3=1$ in $G$ is 2 more than a multiple of 3. Combine this with the answers, and you see that in fact it must be $\equiv 2\pmod{6}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

True: If $g$ has order three, then so does $g^2$ so you can only have an even number of elements of order three.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $x\in G$ has order $3$. Then $x^2=x^{-1}$ has order $3$ as well. Thus, elements of order $3$ come in pairs, and you can’t have an odd number of them.